# Angular $digest error

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Here's the code : [plnkr.co](http://plnkr.co/edit/KsGaUz0CNKkjImwumdBP)

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="example">

<head>
    <script data-require="jquery@1.11.3" data-semver="1.11.3" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.2.28" data-semver="1.2.28" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.28/angular.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="mainCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat="(key, val) in obj | groupPlayers">
        {{key}} = {{ val }}
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

script.js

```
(function() {
  angular
    .module('example', [])

    .controller('mainCtrl', function($scope) {
      $scope.obj = [
        { lastname: 'Jackson', firstname: 'George', score: 6},
        { lastname: 'Jackson', firstname: 'George', score: 10},
        { lastname: 'Smith', firstname: 'Michael', score: 8},
        { lastname: 'Smith', firstname: 'Amanda', score: 2},
        { lastname: 'Smith', firstname: 'Michael', score: 7},
        { lastname: 'Doe', firstname: 'John', score: 4},
      ];
    })

    .filter('groupPlayers', function() {
      return function(list, search) {
        var group = {};
        var key;

        angular.forEach(list, function(item) {
          key = item.lastname + ' ' + item.firstname;
          if(!group[key])
            group[key] = [];
          group[key].push(item.score);
        });

        return group;
      }
    })
  ;
})();
```

I want to group items of an object to display score player by player. I create a angular filter to do this work. The display is fine but I have an error in the console and I don't find the problem after an hour of analyzing !

Error : **10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!**

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using `<div ng-repeat="(key, val) in objFiltered">` and `$scope.objFiltered = $filter('groupPlayers')($scope.obj);` the error doesn't occur anymore.